# Clicking on link to an ID on the same page, truncates everything above the ID (fiddle inside)

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I created a link to an ID that should send the user to a div located somewhere at the top of the same page.
when clicking this link, it does jump to the #id, but everything inside the containing div of that id, gets truncated.

EDIT:

Ok, here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xx6jgLsj/)

CSS:

```
#header {
    width: 1080px;
    min-height: 80px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #badaf6;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}#container {
    width: 1080px;
    min-height: 700px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #FDFDFD;
}
#left {
    float: left;
    width: 700px;
    min-height: 700px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
#marg {
    margin: 11px 20px 10px 18px;
}
#right {
    float: left;
    width: 380px;
    min-height: 700px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

#left #box {  
    margin-top:  0;   
    margin-left:  0;
    background-color:  #ECF4FD; 
    width:  500px;  
    height:  200px;
}

#left, #middle, #right {
    padding-bottom: 999999px;
    margin-bottom: -999999px;
}

#space {
    margin: 30px 0 40px 4px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="header">
</div>
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">
    <div id="space">
      <div id="box">
      </div>
      <p><a href="#box">Click</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
  </div>
  <br style="clear: left;" />
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: It would help if you place your code in http://www.jsfiddle.net.

Comment: Can you at least post the offending href and id. We need some idea of what's going on. Unless someone has had this exact same problem before (and can recognize it from your description) it'll be very difficult to help you without seeing any code...

Comment: what do you mean by "truncates everything above the id"?

Comment: click on the link in the fiddle, you'll see all the white space above the #box gets "lost" forever.

Answer (score 0):

If its okay, you can change your html like this  http://jsfiddle.net/xx6jgLsj/1/

```
<p><a href="#left">Click</p>
```

Comment: thanks, though this is a workaround, I prefer to know what causes the truncation as well

Comment: @rockyraw I don't know, i tried everything else but this was the best way that i had come up with